# GnuPlot splot function with 2d points

Tags: gnuplot

I basically want to draw 2d color surface (or contour plot)
 of rosenbrock function f(x,y) = (a-x)^2 + b * (y-x*x) ^2
and append some points (x,y) on this image.

Sample file with points looks as follows:

```
#x #y
15.00000 12.00000
8.00000 9.00000
```

The thing is, both graphs do not share the same coordinate system on output image:

[coordinate systems do not overlap on each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jgEy.png)

gnuplot code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
    reset
    set terminal png size 700,700
    enhanced set output 'output.png'
    set tmargin screen 1
    set bmargin screen 0
    set border 0 back
    set size square
    xr=20
    yr=20
    set xrange [-xr:xr]
    set yrange [-yr:yr]
    unset key #disablegraph name 
    unset colorbox 
    set surface
     set multiplot
    set view map
    set cntrparam levels 10# contour tenderness
    set style data pm3d
    set pm3d
    set contour
    a=1 #rosenbrock parameter
    b=1 #rosenbrock parameter
```

`#set isosamples 50
splot (a-x) * (a-x) + b * (y-x*x) * (y-x*x) # 2d rosenbrock
unset view
unset pm3d
plot 'data.dat' pt 5,           'data.dat'  using 1:2:($0+1) with labels offset 1 notitle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mixing 2d and surface plots with multiplot is usually a mess. I guess you probably don't need multiplot in this simple case. Maybe something like this is enough:

```
set size square
xr=20
yr=20
set xrange [-xr:xr]
set yrange [-yr:yr]
unset key 
unset colorbox 
set surface
set pm3d map
set contour
set cntrparam levels 10# contour tenderness

rosenbrock(x,y,a,b)= (a-x) * (a-x) + b * (y-x*x) * (y-x*x)

splot rosenbrock(x,y,1,1) w pm3d, 'data.dat' u 1:2:0 w p pt 5, 'data.dat' using 1:2:(1):($0+1) with labels offset 1,1 notitle
```

Comment: your script gives a warning:
line 16: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d"
and there are no labels for particles, even with dgrid3d option.

Comment: small update:
Your script works almost okay, but just do not print labels